# How to check if record exist using vb.net and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

Assuming that I have two tables `Historytable` and `studentInformation table`.

What I would like to do is this:

```
If schoolyear and level exist in Historytable
    update studentInformationtable
else
   INSERT schoolyear,level to Historytable
    update studentInformationtable
```

My stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUpdate] 
    @studentID INT, 
    @SchoolYear Nvarchar(20),
    @levels Nvarchar(20),
    @FirstName Nvarchar(20),
    @SurName Nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN
    IF exists (SELECT SchoolYear, Levels
               FROM StudentHistory WITH (updlock, serializable) 
               WHERE StudentID = @studentID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE StudentInformation
        SET FirstName = @FirstName ,
            Surname = @SurName
        WHERE StudentID = @studentID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Studenthistory (StudentID, SchoolYear, Levels)
        VALUES (@studentID, @SchoolYear, @levels)

        UPDATE StudentInformation
        SET FirstName = @FirstName,
            Surname = @SurName
        WHERE StudentID = @studentID
    END

    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

vb.net code

```
Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.InsertUpdate", cn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", frmView.dgv1.SelectedCells(0).Value)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SurName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtStudLN.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtStudFN.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SchoolYear", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = cboSchoolYear.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@levels", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = cboGradeLevel.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Update New record successfully")
End Using
```

Problem: it does not `INSERT` a new record in my history table when I insert a new `schoolyear` and `level`. Can someone help me to fix my code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUpdate] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

@studentID INT, 
@SchoolYear Nvarchar(20),
@levels Nvarchar(20),
@FirstName Nvarchar(20),
@SurName Nvarchar(20)


AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN

   UPDATE StudentInformation
   SET FirstName = @FirstName ,
   Surname = @SurName
   WHERE StudentID = @studentID

   INSERT INTO Studenthistory (StudentID,SchoolYear, Levels)
   SELECT @studentID,@SchoolYear,@levels
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Studenthistory
        WHERE StudentID = @studentID
   )


COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Notes:

1. There is no need to write the update statement in both if and else parts.
2. The insert statement will add a new record to the `Studenthistory` only if the select statement will return records. The condition in the where clause makes sure that only one record per student will be inserted into the history table.

However, I don't see much point in keeping just one historical record for each student. I think you mean you want to keep the previous values of the school year and levels of each student. If this is true, the query inside the `exists` should be this:

```
SELECT 1
FROM Studenthistory
WHERE StudentID = @studentID
AND SchoolYear = @SchoolYear,
AND Levels = @levels
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Sometimes it's really hard for me to explain my problem in programming in `English`. lol . You're right what i wanted to do is to keep the previous values of the school year and level of each student  Thank you for your patience :)